# How to increase the cracking speed of fcrackzip tool?

Tags: linux-mint, password, settings

So, I have downloaded the fcrackzip tool for linux mint, and I tried using it to test out one of my own .zip files.  But, the only problem that it took way too long to crack the password.  So, is there any settings in linux mint or something along those lines that I can use to speed up the cracking speed of this tool?  Or better yet is there another even better tool for linux or unix?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Without getting into tool specifics, two tips:

1. You should investigate GPU-based crackers. They are are significantly faster than CPU-based crackers (for most hashes, and for most attacks other than straight wordlist attacks).
2. You didn't mention what kind/type of ZIP file you're attacking; different crackers support different ZIP variants (and there a are few), so you'll need to make sure that the tool you pick supports your target type.